# Clarification for LASSO based Cox model using glmnet

Tags: cross-validation, survival, cox-model, glmnet

I am trying to find a variable signature associated with a characteristic. Particularly I am looking to get a prognostic model from multi-variable data for gene expression. I have the "Time (survival years)" and "Status (dead/alive)" data for individuals and I also have expression data for those individuals.

Based on my reading about statistical models and posts [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9785/cox-model-with-lasso) , [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33774/variable-selection-with-lasso?rq=1) and [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58531/using-lasso-from-lars-or-glmnet-package-in-r-for-variable-selection?rq=1), I decided to use multivariate Cox propotional-hazard model. I was reading how to select few best markers, and I found "backward" selection and "LASSO" method to achieve that. Further reading suggested "LASSO" could be a good choice and can be implemented using glmnet package in R.

I divided my data into 60-40 (TRAIN-TEST) proportions, and using the 60% to find those variables and then use them on 40% to find there success as prognostic markers.

The training data has 457 subjects (patients) and 612 covariates (continuous log transformed values). The survivability data is right censored with ~15% Dead cases (Status=1). I don't have any idea about what would be a good number of predictors.

For the TRAIN data, I used the code below.

```
md #expression data
mdsurv #surviablity data( years) and death (0 or 1)
#creating table
eventT<-mdsurv$OS
obsLen<-5 # right censored 5 years
censT<-rep(obsLen,365)
obsT<-pmin(eventT,censT)
status<-eventT<=censT
mdsurv$Status<-as.numeric(status)

keep<-mdsurv$Dead==0 & mdsurv$Status==1
mdsurv$Status[keep]<-0

cvfit<-cv.glmnet(mdt,mdsurv, family = "cox",alpha=1)
plot(cvfit)
c<-coef(cvfit ,s='lambda.min')
```

I am getting 16 genes(covariates) with lambda.min cutoff for coef() and zero with lambda.1se. When I do univariate cox analysis. HR value for some of those genes is less than one. Shall I still use those genes for my test subject or just make a model using the one with HR>=1.

Thanks.
P.S. Edited with new information.More edits

Comment: My previous post had a mistake because I had improperly formatted the data and hence was getting incorrect solution. Now I have updated the post. I am getting significant covariates in the LASSO and univariate cox analysis. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should not be worried by the predictors for which hazard ratios (HR) are < 1. That simply means that increased expression of those predictors is associated with better outcome rather than worse outcome. There is no reason to remove them from further use.

Second, with about 70 events in your training set you typically would have power to fit a standard Cox model with 5 unpenalized predictors without overfitting. (Usual rule of thumb is about 15 events per predictor being considered.) LASSO has identified 16 predictors, but LASSO also has penalized their regression coefficients to lower magnitudes than they would have in a standard Cox model, to avoid overfitting. If you wish to use a training/test setup (see below for why that might not be wise) then you should use the penalized coefficients provided by LASSO to evaluate performance. Do not simply use those predictors as the basis of a standard Cox model, as you then lose the protection against overfitting.

Third, with so few events you typically lose too much information by setting aside separate training and test sets. A more powerful approach can be to develop the model on all of your data to obtain a LASSO model. You then demonstrate the quality of your model-building process on multiple bootstrap samples of the data.

See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/373171/28500) and its links for an overview of how you could proceed. Essentially, after you have your model, you repeat the *entire model-building process*  (cross-validation to choose lambda, model with the LASSO predictor selections and coefficients based on that value of lambda) on multiple bootstrapped samples from all the original data. You evaluate the performance of each model on all the original data. Averaging your estimates of performance for multiple models developed on bootstrapped samples provides a useful measure of the quality of the model-building process. Note that with LASSO you will typically get different predictors selected for each bootstrap sample but this procedure will still document the quality of your modeling approach.

Comment: Thanks @EdM for your explanation. However, I am confused with your first explanation. How can they be best predictor but not significant?  My readings also suggested that LASSO based cox analysis tends to be less conservative in terms of coefficient, but I didn't find information that running cox with and without LASSO could have different answers. Could you also guide me how can I do the bootstrap modeling or an alternative way of selecting variables for cox analysis. Some post suggested backward stepwise cox model isn't appropriate and suggested LASSO based variable selection.

Comment: @PiyushJoshi although finding with LASSO  a "best predictor but not significant" is no longer an issue in your data, it is a real possibility in general. Say that with the number of events and the variability of outcomes that you need to have an HR of 1.5 to pass a standard test of statistical significance in a Cox model. Say that the best predictor in your data has an HR of 1.2. LASSO could identify that predictor yet it would not pass a standard significance test. I've edited the answer to address your revised question.

Comment: Thanks @EdM. I really appreciate your help. I just need two more clarifications. 1) how can generate multiple bootstrapped models. Shall I randomly choose some % (say 60%) of sample, enlarge it original size with repetition, get LASSO based predictor. But then how can I apply it to original data. 2) After multiple bootstrapping, how can I choose final predictors? The ones that are common in all or some other criteria? And what about their coefficient,  would that be average of coef obtain from application of all models  to the original data?

Comment: Can I use bootLasso[https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/HDCI/versions/1.0-2/topics/bootLasso]  package and/or BootValidation [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BootValidation/BootValidation.pdf] package for the algorithm you are suggesting?

Comment: @PiyushJoshi I don't have experience with `BootValidation` but it seems at first glance to do what I suggested. (HDCI doesn't seem to handle Cox models.) The predictors that you report would be those from your original model, with bootstrapping to document the quality of your model-building process. Note that a bootstrapped sample is the same size as your full data set but taken _with replacement_ from your data so that about 1/3 of cases are duplicates. If that package doesn't do what you need, the `boot` package in R provides a general way to proceed.

Comment: @PiyushJoshi the [c060 package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=c060) might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing Cox regression analyses using **glmnet** myself, and ran into this question. The penalization method used in Cox models built by **glmnet** is more generally  *elastic net*. *Elastic net* could be defined as a mix between *LASSO* and *ridge-regression*, and regularizes the data to avoid overfitting as well. I think it would be helpful to ascertain this information, in case you are writing a scientific paper, or something like that.

The reference is: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v039i05

The alpha value setting determines the mix between LASSO and ridge-regression used by glmnet. The default is `alpha=1`, which is pure LASSO as used in this question. Other values can be chosen: `alpha=0` is pure ridge regression, while intermediate values combine LASSO and ridge.

Comment: You are correct that the `glmnet()` function does _allow for_ elastic net. That's a strength of the package. The tradeoff between LASSO and ridge regression is determined by the `alpha` parameter setting in the call to the function. The default value for that setting, however, is `alpha=1`, which is all LASSO, no ridge, according to the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf). That setting was used explicitly in the OP. Unless you provide a different value for `alpha`, the function will do a LASSO fit by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, @EdM!

Comment: There's no need to apologize. Your answer made an important point--`glmnet()` does do elastic net, it's just that the LASSO extreme is what it chooses by default. And your link to the paper is helpful. Editing an answer when you realize that a prior version was incomplete or misleading is an important way that contributors to this site learn more about statistics, one that I have frequently engaged in and for which no apology is necessary. I'll edit your question to suggest a way to proceed, without apology.

Comment: The edit is great, thank you!

Comment: @EdM, appreciate your answers on many questions. I have a follow-up question on glmnet. How could we find the best alpha? Is there a formal procedure to do this? i have a time to event datasets with less than 50 events and many biomarker measurements as potential covariates.. my intuition is to use LASSO to select simplest model but I've also read that ridge could also eliminate certain covariates so i'm confused with what to do.. Thanks!

Comment: @user2157668 [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/275183/28500) and its link to the `glmnet` [documentation on cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/275183/28500) show how to optimize both alpha and lambda. Set up a grid of alpha values and find the optimum lambda value and associated performance estimate for each alpha. For reliable comparison, keep the folds constant across alpha choices by specifying a `foldid` identifier for cases. Find the best performance combination overall. Ridge on its own doesn't eliminate predictors; combining with LASSO in elastic net does.

Comment: @EdM, thanks for your answer! I think the glmnet section mentioned is where they tried cv1, cv.5, cv0, right? a follow-up question is how many alphas to try? i could go from 0 to 1 and use 0.1 increment or 0.01 increment or even 0.001.. will say 0, 0.1, 0.2, etc to 0.9, 1 be enough resolution of alphas?

Comment: @user2157668 In principle, "the more the merrier." It's all a matter of how much resolution you want. You might start with a coarse grid of alpha values to start, then do progressively finer grids near the values that seem to work best if you have more data than you can handle with a fine grid over the whole range.

Comment: @EdM right, that's what i thought.. i just wonder if there is a automatic way to pick the best alph, like what cv.glmnet doing for lambda.. i saw caret has that train() function to simultaneously find alpha and lambda.. i'll give that a try as well.  I also found the glmnetUtils package that has a CV for alpha.. by default it picked 11 alphas..

Comment: @user2157668 [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/275183/28500) suggests that the approach used by `caret` might not be the best way to go. There's also a practical issue in choosing alpha: how many total predictors do you actually want to include? If you're open to including them all, full ridge regression (without any predictor selection) can work well.

Comment: @EdM i have hundreds of biomarkers.. and want to do feature selection through LASSO and focus on several covariates in the end.. elastic net might be better than LASSO is my thought but i have a feeling the results will be similar

Comment: @user2157668 instead of continuing with comments on another user's answer to yet another user's question, why don't you post a new question directly related to questions about your current project? If the questions are covered by other posts here your question might be closed, but even that might be more efficient than our chat here. I suspect that you will want a partially penalized model, maybe not penalizing the covariates at all, but that would depend on details of your data.

Comment: @EdM, yeah, let me try them a bit and i'll create a new questions later. thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Hi @user2157668. You can use {tidymodels} to create the grid and tune your alpha parameter to find the optimal for your model. I was in a tidymodels workshop recently and [these slides](https://workshops.tidymodels.org/slides/06-tuning-hyperparameters.html) are for grid creation and tuning. You should also have a look at [tidymodels website](https://www.tidymodels.org/).

Comment: @Fla28, thanks for sharing! i'll take a look